# "L'épée de Damoclès"

Tags: grec

L'expression "l'épée de Damoclès" (pour décrire une situation particulièrement dangereuse ou pénible qui peut se produire d'un moment à l'autre [[1]](https://www.edilivre.com/lexpression-de-la-semaine-epee-de-damocles/)) est-elle reconnue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L’expression est connue et employée dans une situation ou la personne concernée par « l’épée de Damoclès » ne peut plus éviter le danger par sa propre volonté, sa vie  — ou sa bonne fortune — dépend d’un avenir imprévisible.

En revanche, si cette même personne emploie une « épée à double tranchant », elle peut agir pour anéantir son ennemi, mais, son épée mal maîtrisée peut se retourner sévèrement contre elle.

À la fin, le résultat est le même, mais les situations inconfortables de départ son opposées : action impossible ou action pour s’en sortir envisageable.

Comment: Je pense que l'on doit toujours employer le singulier avec "double", donc "double tranchants" n'est selon moi pas correct. Cela dit on digresse, la question d'origine ne parle pas de double tranchant et sans la réponse de LPH on n'en parlerait sans doute pas non plus :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. — Ngram est sans appel et vous donne raison https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=double+tranchants%2Cdouble+tranchant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdouble%20tranchant%3B%2Cc0 . Ceci dit, LPH permet à la Sérendipité de se manifester sur les sens cachés derrière les idiomes :-)

Answer (score -2):

Elle l'est et elle est même très connue tout aussi bien qu'elle est utile et un bon moyen imagé de parler de situation qui comprennent un danger constant, comme l'expression similaire en sens « à double tranchant » ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+double+tranchant%2C%C3%A9p%C3%A9e+de+Damocl%C3%A8s&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20double%20tranchant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9p%C3%A9e%20de%20Damocl%C3%A8s%3B%2Cc0)). Il semble que de nos jours, cependant, « à double tranchant » devienne plus populaire.

---

La similarité à laquelle je réfère peut être vérifiée dans l'article suivant bien que l'auteur ait voulu en faire un peu trop semble-t-il et qu'il ait utilisé un tranchant de trop : « https://www.humanite.fr/node/220961 ».

Comment: Le double tranchant n'a pas grand chose à voir avec l'épée de Damoclès.

Comment: @jlliagre Au contraire, il me semble, dans les deux cas il s'agit d'un danger ou d'un risque permanent.

Comment: Non, ça n'a rien à voir, à part l'image de la lame. L'épée de Damoclès représente une situation purement négative extérieure et non maîtrisée alors que le double tranchant indique que quelque chose de positif que l'on maîtrise, que l'on a en main, peut éventuellement avoir aussi des conséquences négatives.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne suis pas d'accord 1/ (Damoclès) On l’utilise pour signifier la présence d’un danger constant qui peut arriver et nous frapper à tout moment. 2/ Le tyran tenta de lui faire comprendre que sa vie était loin d’être si agréable qu’il le pensait, mais Damoclès n’en crut pas un mot, c’est pourquoi il proposa à ce dernier de le laisser prendre sa place le temps d’une journée, pour le laisser juger de la situation d’un monarque en toute connaissance de cause. [On a même ici le double tranchant dans la vie du potentat.] voir la réf. donnée dans la question (source des  explications).

Comment: @jlliagre De plus, l'image de la lame avec ses deux tranchants ne doit absolument pas être impliquée là-dedans : elle est strictement sans intérêt, c'est une idée complètement sans objet.

Comment: Mais oui, bien sûr. Il ne faut pas prendre la métaphore pour ce qu'elle est. Pourquoi faudrait-il donc penser à une lame quant on évoque l'épée de Damoclès ou une arme à double tranchant ? Je ne sais pas pourquoi je perds mon temps à essayer de te faire entendre raison. Je sors.

Comment: À mon avis tu confonds ce que Denys L'Ancien voulait montrer à Damoclès, cette dualité bénéfice-risque, et le sens de l'expression, qui n'a rien à voir avec cette dualité, alors que le sens de l'arme à double-tranchant lui, oui.

Comment: Moins un car jlliagre a raison, les 2 expressions n'ont strictement rien à voir ensemble...

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'il ait utilisé un tranchant de trop, mais bien qu'il a combiné 2 expressions en une : l'épée de Damoclès (un risque bien présent) et l'arme à double tranchant. Si je comprends bien l'article, il dit en gros que le patronat fait pendre une épée de damoclès au dessus de la tête des travailleurs avec sa menace, mais que "c'est l'énorme chantier des droits des salariés qui pourrait être grand ouvert à cette occasion, a contrario du but recherché par le MEDEF" (d'où le double tranchant).